# How to enter rails console on production via capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, capistrano

I want to enter the rails console on production server from my local machine via capistrano.
I found some gists, e.g. https://gist.github.com/813291 and when I enter console via

```
cap production console
```

I get the following result

```
192-168-0-100:foldername username $ cap console RAILS_ENV=production
  * executing `console'
  * executing "cd /var/www/myapp/current && rails console production"
    servers: ["www.example.de"]
    [www.example.de] executing command
    [www.example.de] rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'cd /var/www/myapp/current && rails console production'
/var/www/myapp/releases/20120305102218/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
```

and thats it... Now I can enter some text, but nothing happens...

Has anybody an idea how to get that work or another solution for my problem?

Comment: May be it can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347811/is-there-a-way-to-use-capistrano-or-similar-to-remotely-interact-with-rails-co

Answer (score 11):

I've added my own tasks for this kind of thing:

```
namespace :rails do
  desc "Remote console"
  task :console, :roles => :app do
    run_interactively "bundle exec rails console #{rails_env}"
  end

  desc "Remote dbconsole"
  task :dbconsole, :roles => :app do
    run_interactively "bundle exec rails dbconsole #{rails_env}"
  end
end

def run_interactively(command)
  server ||= find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
  exec %Q(ssh #{user}@#{myproductionhost} -t '#{command}')
end
```

I now say `cap rails:console` and get a console.

Answer (score 5):

For Capistrano 3 you can add these lines in your `config/deploy`:

```
namespace :rails do
  desc 'Open a rails console `cap [staging] rails:console [server_index default: 0]`'
  task :console do    
    server = roles(:app)[ARGV[2].to_i]

    puts "Opening a console on: #{server.hostname}...."

    cmd = "ssh #{server.user}@#{server.hostname} -t 'cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)} bundle exec rails console'"

    puts cmd

    exec cmd
  end
end
```

To open the first server in the servers list:

```
cap [staging] rails:console
```

To open the second server in the servers list:

```
cap [staging] rails:console 1
```

Reference: [Opening a Rails console with Capistrano 3](http://pablocantero.com/blog/2014/06/16/opening-a-rails-console-with-capistrano-3/)

[exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) is needed to replace the current process, otherwise you will not be able to interact with the rails console.

Answer (score 3):

A simple **Capistrano 3** solution may be:

```
namespace :rails do
  desc "Run the console on a remote server."
  task :console do
    on roles(:app) do |h|
      execute_interactively "RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)} bundle exec rails console", h.user
    end
  end

  def execute_interactively(command, user)
    info "Connecting with #{user}@#{host}"
    cmd = "ssh #{user}@#{host} -p 22 -t 'cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current && #{command}'"
    exec cmd
  end
end
```

Then you can call it say, on staging, with: `cap staging rails:console`. Have fun!

Comment: The problem is when you have more than one server in the servers list, this task ^^^ will try to open the console in all of them. :/

Answer (score 1):

For Capistrano > 3.5 and rbenv. Working in 2021

```
namespace :rails do
  desc "Open the rails console on one of the remote servers"
  task :console do |current_task|
    on roles(:app) do |server|
      server ||= find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
      exec %Q[ssh -l #{server.user||fetch(:user)} #{server.hostname} -p #{server.port || 22} -t 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd #{release_path}; bin/rails console -e production']
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fiddled with that approach as well, but then resorted to avoiding building my own interactive SSH shell client and just went with [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/1115513) I found that simply uses good old SSH. This might not be suitable if you have some weird SSH gateway proxying going on, but for logging into a box and performing some operations, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, capistrano isn't built to work very well with interactive terminals.

If you have to execute things in multiple terminals, I'd suggest iterm, which has a "send to all windows" function that works very well for me:

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat difficult environment, which is influx ... So `bash -lc` isn't really an option right now. My solution is similar to @Rocco, but it's a bit more refined.

```
# run a command in the `current` directory of `deploy_to`
def run_interactively(command)
  # select a random server to run on
  server = find_servers_for_task(current_task).sample
  # cobble together a shell environment
  app_env = fetch("default_environment", {}).map{|k,v| "#{k}=\"#{v}\""}.join(' ')
  # Import the default environment, cd to the currently deployed app, run the command
  command = %Q(ssh -tt -i #{ssh_options[:keys]} #{user}@#{server} "env #{app_env} bash -c 'cd #{deploy_to}/current; #{command}'")
  puts command
  exec command
end

namespace :rails do
  desc "rails console on a sidekiq worker"
  task :console, role: :sidekiq_normal do
    run_interactively "bundle exec rails console #{rails_env}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Rails console in Capistrano 3 see this gist: https://gist.github.com/joost/9343156

Answer (score 0):

I have just used [capistrano-rails-console gem](https://gitlab.com/ydkn/capistrano-rails-console) to open rails console and it works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32446511)